# Validate 2 check boxes and 2 text boxes

Tags: javascript, validation, checkbox, textbox

My goal is user require to choose at least one option from 2 check boxes and 2 text boxes. If user do not select anything, the system will prompt the user to select at least one.

However, right now, the user need to select everything which is not what I want.

Below are my codes..

Help will be appreciate..Thanks! :)

At    index.jsp

```
<form method="post" name="searchform" onsubmit="return validateForm();">
Date: <input name="date" readonly="readonly" />
Number: <input type="text" name="on">
<input type="checkbox" id="completed"> Option A
<input type="checkbox" id="pending"> Option B
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

At **javascript**

```
function validateForm() {
    var radio1 = document.getElementById('pending').checked;
    var radio2 = document.getElementById('completed').checked;

    var on = document.forms["searchform"]["on"].value;
    var date = document.forms["searchform"]["date"].value;


    if ((radio1 == "") || (radio2 == "") || (on == null || on="") || (date == null || date =="")){
        alert('Please Choose at least 1 Option');
        return false;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply change your outer `||` to `&&`

```
if ((radio1 == "") && (radio2 == "") && (on == null || on="") && (date == null || date =="")){
    alert('Please Choose at least 1 Option');
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
if (((radio1 == "") && (radio2 == "")) &&(on == null || on="") && (date == null || date =="")){
        alert('Please Choose at least 1 Option');
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks but that it is not what I want. I want user to choose CHECKBOX A OR CHECKBOX B OR TEXTBOX A OR TEXTBOX B .. From your code, the user need to choose 1 CHECKBOX and 1 TEXTBOX.

Comment: Hi Sach.. @Rafa El managed to answer my question.. Thanks for your help! :)